# Python 3.6 pygame crashing

Tags: python, pygame

I tried using a really simple code to create a rectangle shape using python 3.6.1. I'm not sure if the code i'm using is causing the program to crash every time I use it or if someone could give me advice on what might be happening between my pygame module, my cmd and the code i'm using. [image: screenshot of windows]

Comment: @Alastair False, pygame requires the user to have and infinite `while` loop to simulate the continuous event loop

Comment: @jayardot although the code is fairly simple, we would like you to copy and paste your code to the question itself as well (to avoid misreading, and prevent the risk of the hosting site taking down the image).

Comment: What crash? Why do you think there's a crash here?

Comment: okay so by crash i meant as soon as the program window opens, it becomes unresponsive. if i move my mouse over it i just get the blue circle like its processing something.

Answer (score 0):

When I run your code, the window loads and displays the rectangle, however, I think you issue involves trying to quit the program. To do that, you need to have an event loop that will kill the game when the user quits out of the game loop:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

isrunning = True

window = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 400))

while isrunning:
   for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                isrunning = False
    pygame.draw.rect(window, (255, 0, 0), (0, 0, 50, 30)) #here, access the rect method

    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Glad to help. Please consider accepting this answer so that other users know your question is answered. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to fill the screen with a background color. If you want black, you still will need to manually set the background color to black.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 400))

while True:
    window.fill(0, 0, 0)
    pygame.draw.rect(window, (255, 0, 0), (0, 0, 50, 30))

    pygame.display.flip()
```

And it will be better if you add a frame rate, and add an event loop.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 400))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while True:
    window.fill(0, 0, 0)
    pygame.event.pump()  # use pump if you’re not planning to catch any event

    pygame.draw.rect(window, (255, 0, 0), (0, 0, 50, 30))
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(50)  # add the frame rate, should always be > 30
```

And as a general tip, use `flip()` if you’re not passing any the rectangle argument to `update()`

Answer (score 0):

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 400))
while True:
    pygame.draw.rect(window, (255,0,0),
        (0, 0, 50, 30))
    pygame.display.update()
```

heres the code

Comment: Edit your post by clicking the edit button, DO NOT post a non-answer as an answer, but very appropriated that you paste your code. Delete this answer please.